# Get a value from api only if it doesn't exist in the store with svelte

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, rendering, svelte, urql

I'm trying to make a function in svelte and urql to get the user logged only if it's already setted in the store. Otherwise i get it from the api.

In my login submit form i set in the store the user value :

```
 function onSubmit() {
    if ($data?.user) {
      userLogged.update((s) => ({
        ...s,
        user: $data?.user,
      }));
    }
  });
```

and in another component here i try to get the value from store if exist or from api :

```
<script lang="ts">
let user: any;
    const getUser = () => {
        let user = get(userLogged);
    
        if (user.user !== null) {
          return user;
        } else {
          const userQuery = queryStore({
            client: getContextClient(),
            query: USER_QUERY,
          });
          userQuery.subscribe((val) => {
            console.log("val ?", val?.data?.user);
            userLogged.update((s) => ({ ...s, user: val?.data?.user }));
    
            user = val?.data?.user;
           
          });
          return user;
        }
      };
    user = getUser();
    console.log("user", user);
</script>
```

But when i refresh the page at the first rendering the console.log return undefined and then when the component is updated it return the user correctly. I don't understand why because the console.log into the subscribe return the good value everytime and i assign it to the user variable

Comment: Where is `getUser` running from? `onMount()`...?  If you're using Sveltekit (Not Svelte), consider using cookies to store user state. You can read more here: https://blog.logrocket.com/authentication-svelte-using-cookies/

Comment: getUser() is run at the top of my List.svelte component between the script tag. I declared a global variable user to assign it and use it into my template.
Ideally i want to export the function then to reuse it in the other components.
I edited the code.
I do not use SvelteKit, juste Svelte framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it worked. I just set my store value in a parent component and imported it it the different children, and then the value is correctly get back in the first rendering.